# How to get correctly array from new HttpClient?

Tags: angular4, httpclient

Всем привет! Помогите разобраться, не могу понять почему с новым HttpClient не работает, есть компонент, класс с апи, и сервис, но это не работает.

Api.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class Api {
  constructor(public httpClient: HttpClient) {}
  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/';

  private getUrl(url: string = ''): string {
    return this.baseUrl + url;
  }

  public get(url: string = ''): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.getUrl(url));
  }

}
```

MembersService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Api } from './api';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export interface Member {
  id: string;
  phone: string;
  mobile: string;
  dep: string;
  email: string;
  owner: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class MembersService extends Api {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    super(http);
  }

  getMembers(): Observable<Array<Member>> {
    return this.http.get<Array<Member>>('api/test');
  }
}
```

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MembersService } from '../services/members.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'project',
  templateUrl: './project.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./project.component.css']
})
export class ProjectComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private memberService: MembersService  ) {
  }

  members: string[];


  ngOnInit() {
    this.members = this.memberService.getMembers();
  }
}
```

Ошибка:

> ERROR in src/app/project/project.component.ts(30,5): error TS2322:
>   Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
>   Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Observable'.

Comment: ты не правильно берешь данные с Observable. Данные нужно брать внутри subscribe()

Comment: зачем эта строчка super(http)?????

Answer (score 1):

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MembersService} from './members.service';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
     selector: 'project',
     templateUrl: './project.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./project.component.css']
})
export class ProjectComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private memberService: MembersService) {
    }

    members: string[];

    private dataSub: Subscription;


    ngOnInit() {
        if (this.dataSub && !this.dataSub.closed) {
            this.dataSub.unsubscribe();
        }
        this.dataSub = this.memberService.getMembers().subscribe((res: any) => {
            this.members = res;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44866124/angular-4-invalidpipeargument-object-object-for-pipe-asyncpipe